# Proof of Chapter 2 Proposition 2.6a in Silverman Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves

The following is Proposition 2.6(a) in Silverman's AEC:

"Let $\phi: C_1 \rightarrow C_2$ be a nonconstant rational map of smooth (projective) curves over an algebraically closed field $K$. Then $\forall Q \in C_2,$ $\displaystyle \sum_{P \,\in\, \phi^{-1}(Q)} e_{\phi}(P) = $ [$K(C_1)$: $\phi^*K(C_2)].$"

We define the pullback $\phi^*: K(C_2) \hookrightarrow K(C_1)$ as an inclusion of fields ($\phi^*(f) = f \circ \phi$) and the ramification index of $\phi$ at $P$ as $e_{\phi}(P) = $ ord$_{P}(\phi^*t_{\phi(P)}),$ where $t_{\phi(P)}$ is a uniformizer of $Q = \phi(P)$ in $K(C_2).$

This Proposition seems to be analogous to the following well-known result in Algebraic Number Theory:

"Let $A$ be a Dedekind Domain, $K$ = Quot$(A)$, $L$ a finite separable field extension of $K$, and $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $L$ (call this the $AKLB$ setup). Then given a nonzero prime $\mathfrak{p} \in \mbox{Spec}(A)$, we have $\displaystyle \sum_{\mathfrak{P}\,|\,\mathfrak{p}} e_{_{\mathfrak{P}}}f_{_{\mathfrak{P}}} = $ [$L$ : $K$]."

I'm having issues exhibiting the objects in Proposition 2.6(a) into the framework of the $AKLB$ setup. $K$ and $L$ should be $\phi^*K(C_2)$ and $K(C_1)$, respectively, but can we find $A$ and $B$ to do anything meaningful? Assuming that this association is correct, it is easy to see that $f_{\phi}(P) = 1$ for all $P \in C_1$ (as the base residue field is isomorphic to the algebraically closed field $K$). It would also make sense to associate the point $Q \in C_2$ with a prime of $A$ and the elements $P \in \phi^{-1}(Q)$ as primes in $B$ lying above $A.$ But the key is to find the right $A$ and $B$ that shows this. My trial and error candidates for $A$ and $B$ seem fruitless, because it always seems that one of these rings is difficult to work with.

I managed to find a convincing proof of this in Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry," but the proof had no number theory flavor to it. There is clearly a number theory context to this that I can't seem to exhibit. I also have seen a proof that uses the theory of divisors, but this material on divisors in Silverman occurs later on. My main question is to find what $A$ and $B$ should be to make this proof work. Does anyone know how to relate the two Propositions above explicitly?

Edit: One detail I realized I overlooked is that $K(C_1)$ might not necessarily be separable over $\phi^*K(C_2)$. Is there a way to adjust the $AKLB$ setup, since $L/K$ has to be separable for this to work?

Comment: Since $\phi$ is finite (and so affine) take any affine neighborhood $\text{Spec}(A)$ of $Q$. Then, $\phi^{-1}(\text{Spec}(A))=\text{Spec}(B)$ for some $B$. Your 'AKLB' setup is then $A K(C_2)K(C_1)B$.

Comment: The difference to number theory is, perhaps, that there is no *unique* candidate for the roles of $A$ and $B$. The following works. At the level of the ring $\Bbb{Z}$ the natural analogue is the polynomial ring $K[x]$. This can be constructed geometrically as the subring of the field $K(x)$ consisting of those elements whose only pole is at the infinity. We can then use its integral closures in the bigger fields much like we use the integral closures of $\Bbb{Z}$ in the number fields.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen There is no canonical choice but one can work in 'charts'.

Comment: The catch is that there is no compelling reason to look at the functions with poles only at the point of infinity *in particular*. Any other point would serve equally well. Our familiarity with the polynomial ring $K[x]$ just makes the point at infinity a not-unnatural preference. Observe that you cannot use the ring of functions with no poles - you only get the constants then, and that is too small a ring.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Sorry, but I'm not too seasoned in Algebraic Geometry. Can you elaborate on your first comment a little more?

Comment: But, anyway, you're right. This is algebraic number theory all again. Or, some people might be more inclined to turn the tables and call algebraic number theory part of geometry! I found [Michael Rosen's book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953359) a very illuminating account of the similarity between the extensions of $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$ and $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @spadey Choose any affine open neighborhood of $Q$. Then, this will give you a subring $A\subseteq K(C_2)$. Let $B$ be the integral closure in $K(C_1)$. Apply your result to this. As for your issue with the separability, this is not really an issue. If I recall, this is a common assumption in number theory so that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module. For varieties over a field, the analogous result is automatic (separable extension or not). See here: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/145Page/handouts/intclos.pdf